# Как правильно спроектировать класс в Python?

Tags: python

Есть класс-диспетчер `A` и класс `B` с методом-обработчиком события:

```
class A:

    def register_handler(handler):
        pass

class B:
    data = some_data
    handler = None

    def __init__(self):
         self.make_handlers()

    def make_handlers(self)
        def some_handler0()
           data1 = self.data

        def some_handler1():
            A.register_handler(some_handler0)

        self.handler = some_handler1
```

В результате, предположим, выполнения функции `C`, основной обработчик класса `B` подписывается на события через `register_handler`. Но, как следует из кода, он подписывает другой обработчик внутри себя.

От класса B наследуется великое множество других классов, и мне не нравится, что метод `make_handlers` не соответствует принципам DRY, и при для переопределения мне нужно её переписывать. Как это решить?

*Предполагаю, что мне нужно просто определить сами методы в классе, и в их определении в make_handlers просто вызывать их из класса. А переопределять `make_handlers` при помощи `super`*

Опыт в Python не сильно большой, но хочется сразу уходить от плохо поддерживаемого и расширяемого г****кода. Помогите мне.

Comment: Вы какой-то паттерн хотите применить, не пойму? Попробуйте переопределение handler вынести в отдельную сущность, в классе B сделать ссылку на него, потом плодите наследников B и пере-определяйте handler всем сразу.

Comment: Я использую модуль, в котором определен диспетчер событий. При определенном событии вызываются по списку хэндлеры. Но обработчик вызывается как обычная функция. Если я передам ссылку на метод, то ему будет необходим класс или инстанс. В Статический метод не будет иметь доступ к данным класса, поэтому я определяю обработчики в отдельной функции. Но они разные (хоть и не все) для разных классов-наследников. Поэтому мне нужно переопределять их. А сделать при текущей структуре это можно только полностью переопределив make_handlers

Comment: вы представили кусок запутанного решения какой-то задачи. Что за задача из имён типа A, B понять сложно. Код, который показан, не по  назначению использует функциональность классов (смешивание переменных классов и экземпляра, передача в качестве self в класс объекта функции, переопределение локального имени без эффекта).

Comment: Вероятно вам более комфортно в другом языке. Попробуйте решить задачу на нём, получив читаемый код, а потом попробуйте идиоматически перевести на Питон. Может быть вам стоит выкинуть все эти иерархии и просто функцию принимать в качестве аргумента. Подсказка: `экземпляр.метод` в Питоне это функция, которая имеет доступ к self (`экземпляр` в данном случае)

Answer (score 0):

ничего не понял, но кажется както так

```
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def register_handler(handler):
        print('A:', handler())

class B:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.handler = lambda: A.register_handler(self.some_handler)

    def some_handler(self, c):
        return 'B: {c} data = {dt}'.format(c=c, dt=self.data)

class C(B):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__(data)
        self.handler = self.handler()

    def some_handler(self):
        c = 'C:(%s)' % id(self)
        return super().some_handler(c)

c1 = C('qwe')
c2 = C('asd')
```

out:

```
A: B: C:(64017424) data = qwe
A: B: C:(64017456) data = asd
```

Answer (score 0):

чтоб перестать писать как вы выразились Г** код то
1. подружитесь с pylint -  статистический анализатор.
2. Ваш код по определению не запустится - синтаксические ошибки:

вот ваш пример исправленный
class A:

```
def register_handler(handler):
    pass
```

class B:
    data = none
    handler = None

```
def __init__(self, init_data=None):
    self.data = init_data
    self.make_handlers()

def make_handlers(self):
    def some_handler0():
       data1 = self.data

    def some_handler1():
        A.register_handler(some_handler0)

    self.handler = some_handler1
```

а вот пример оценки вашего кода примера только что:

W: 17, 0: Bad indentation. Found 11 spaces, expected 12 (bad-indentation)
C:  1, 0: Missing module docstring (missing-docstring)
C:  1, 0: Invalid class name "A" (invalid-name)
C:  1, 0: Missing class docstring (missing-docstring)
C:  3, 4: Missing method docstring (missing-docstring)
E:  3, 4: Method should have "self" as first argument (no-self-argument)
R:  1, 0: Too few public methods (1/2) (too-few-public-methods)
C:  7, 0: Invalid class name "B" (invalid-name)
C:  7, 0: Missing class docstring (missing-docstring)
E:  8,11: Undefined variable 'none' (undefined-variable)
C: 15, 4: Missing method docstring (missing-docstring)
C: 16, 8: Missing function docstring (missing-docstring)
W: 17,11: Unused variable 'data1' (unused-variable)
C: 19, 8: Missing function docstring (missing-docstring)
R:  7, 0: Too few public methods (1/2) (too-few-public-methods)

---

Your code has been rated at -5.33/10 (previous run: -4.29/10, -1.05)

ну да самый строгий анализатор :)

и по подробнее будьте добры что вы хотите - можно диаграммы :)
и таки да не поленитесь посмотрите что говорит анализатор,
я понимаю пример учебный но тем не менее...
в интернете есть все ответы, что не понравилось pylint

Comment: Пример не просто учебный. Пример упрощенный. Там большой кусок кода, который я не могу показывать. Естественно пример не запустится, мне хотелось узнать о приемлемом шаблоне проектирования. Но, видимо, я как-то сложно описал.

Answer (score 0):

```
from abc import abstractmethod, abstractstaticmethod,  ABCMeta

class IDispetcher (object):
    __metaclass__=ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def get_some(self):
        """Получить чего либо"""
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def save_all(self):
        """Сохранить чего либо"""
        pass

    @abstractstaticmethod
    def do_static(self):
        """Не придумал зачем мне оно, но пусть будет"""

"""
Начинаем фигачить наследников
"""


class IOrders(IDispetcher):

    def get_some(self, uid=None):
        """В данном случае получаем документ по ид"""
        pass

    def save_all(self):
        """В данном случае сохраняем документы"""
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def do_static(self):
        """Что то делаем с документом"""
        pass


class IUsers(IDispetcher):

    def get_some(self, uid=None):
        """Получаем пользователя по ид"""
        pass

    def save_all(self):
        """Сохраняем пользователей"""

    @staticmethod
    def do_static(self):
        """Делаем что-то статически с пользователем"""


class Dispatcher(object):

    @staticmethod
    def register_handler(self, handler):
        """ Типа зарегали метод """
        pass

class OrderDispatcher(object):

    def __init__(self):
        """Ну типа конструктор """
        self.interface = IUsers()
        self.make_handlers()
        self.data = '1234567890'        # так для примера
        # диспетчер у вас скорее всего сингл-тон

    def make_handlers(self):

        def handler0():
            """типа вернем мы данные """
            return self.data

        def handler1():
            """регаем свой обработчик"""
            Dispatcher.register_handler(self.interface.get_some())

        def handler2():
            """Регаем еще один обработчик"""
            Dispatcher.register_handler(self.interface.save_all())
```

Навеянно этим 
[image: Схема]

реализация наверное сделанна не совсем корректно - но смысл я думаю понятен.